# How to find available (unused) IDs to be reused for XML elements

Tags: python, xml, while-loop, attributes

I'm new to Python and trying to write an XML Editor.

So far I got it to create a fresh XML file, to edit existing entries and to add new entries. Now I want to asign unique IDs to certain entries and don't have the slightest clue how to do that.

My idea so far is to get the program to iterate through all elements, define the IDs and then check what's the lowest asigned number not in use to define and use that as ID for the new entry. But how do I do that code-wise?

And since I'm on it ... is it a good idea to define a minimum length for the IDs? If not they would start with 1. I guess having IDs like 100001 etc. will be better?

I'd be happy about some help.

Here's the relevant part of code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("KnowledgeBase.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

for elem in root.iter():
print(elem.tag,elem.attrib,elem.text)       # lists all categories with attributes and text

print()

new_adv_id = **???**                        # **that's the part I need help with**
new_adv = input("New entry: ")              # defines new_adv, user input provides content for the new entry

article = ET.Element("Article")
category = ET.SubElement(article, "Category")
subcat = ET.SubElement(article, "SubCat")
topic = ET.SubElement(article, "Topic")
adv = ET.SubElement(article, "Advice")
adv.set("ID", new_adv_id)                   # new_adv_id goes here
adv.text = new_adv                          # new_adv user input goes here
root.insert(0, article)

ET.indent(tree, '  ')                       # prettify XML code (insert linebreaks and indents)
tree.write("KnowledgeBase.xml", encoding="utf-8", xml_declaration=True) # save back to file
```

The resulting XML file looks/should look like this:

**BEFORE:**

```
<KnowledgeBase>                             
  <Article>
    <Category />
    <SubCat />
    <Topic />
    <Advice ID="1">new_adv</Advice>
  </Article>
</KnowledgeBase>
```

**AFTER:**

```
<KnowledgeBase>                             
  <Article>
    <Category />
    <SubCat />
    <Topic />
    <Advice ID="1">new_adv</Advice>    #ID="100001"?
  </Article>
  <Article>
    <Category />
    <SubCat />
    <Topic />
    <Advice ID="2">new_adv</Advice>    #ID="100002"?
  </Article>
</KnowledgeBase>
```

Comment: What is your specific problem? To find all IDs already in use?

Comment: Generally there is no need to start with very high ID numbers. Depending on the use case you may reserve the first few numbers for special usages like ID 0 for "unknown ID".

Comment: My problem is to find an ID that is not in use.

Comment: To find an ID that isn't in use requires to know all IDs that are in use. Have you solved that already?

Comment: Well, this part: 

for elem in root.iter():
print(elem.tag,elem.attrib,elem.text) 

includes all the IDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my suggestion. Create a list of used ID’s with the `findall()` function of `xml.etree.ElementTree`, search for ID gaps, use the gap first or increase the highest ID:
*Comment: The ID should always given by the system and not the user.*

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = """
<KnowledgeBase>                             
  <Article>
    <Category />
    <SubCat />
    <Topic />
    <Advice ID="1">new_adv</Advice>    #ID="100001"?
  </Article>
  <Article>
    <Category />
    <SubCat />
    <Topic />
    <Advice ID="4">new_adv</Advice>    #ID="100002"?
  </Article>
</KnowledgeBase>
"""''

def unused_numbers(usedL):
    L = usedL
    Lmax = max(L)
    l = len(L)
    ideal_L = range(1, Lmax+1, 1)
    
    num_tank = [x for x in ideal_L if x not in L]
    print("List of free numbers", num_tank)
    
    if len(num_tank) > 0:
        next_number = num_tank.pop(0)
        print("Next used number", next_number)
        print("still available free numbers", num_tank)
    else:
        next_number = Lmax+1 
    return str(next_number)


root = ET.fromstring(xml)

print("\n")
# First part, select used list

Lexample =  root.findall(".//Advice[@ID]")
L= []
for n in Lexample:
    print(n.attrib['ID'])
    L.append(int(n.attrib['ID']))
    

print("\n")
# Second part, pick up unused number

# Assume your list looks like this for test only
#L = [1,7,5,4,2]

new_free_number = unused_numbers(L)
print("New No.", new_free_number)

# add new_free_number to the tag attribute
```

Output:

```
1
4


List of free numbers [2, 3]
Next used number 2
still available free numbers [3]
New No. 2
```

Comment: "The ID should always given by the system and not the user." Absolutely. I ended up displying all entries and tell the user to add +1 to the last ID manually yesterday. Your code will definitely help to fix that.

Comment: I still have some questions: When I replace the ID in '<Advice ID="1">' in the XML with '100001' and do the same with ID2, and replace 'ideal_L = range(1, Lmax+1, 1)' with 'ideal_L = range(100001, Lmax+1, 1)' accordingly, the script will stop printing 'Next used number 2' and 'still available free numbers [3]'. The 2 lines are not essential, but I would like to understand it. The final result still shows up correctly as 100003 and the code seems to rely one the calculations, that are used for these 2 hiding lines.

Comment: Edit: Oh nevermind, I see ... Those 2 lines only show IDs within gaps of taken IDs.

Comment: @StoneyWaters, You can delete the print() statements, I added this only for clarification of the concept.

Comment: Right. I also removed 'l = len(L)', which I could not find to be used in other context. Or did I miss something?

Comment: Right. This is the length of you list or let say your amount of articles. I thought it could be helpful to check, if the max. ID value  minus list length is equal zero, so in this case you have no gap. But I am not implemented this in the end. Maybe you can improve the number picker function :-).

Comment: Ah, ok. Yes, might be intersting as a value.